# What does the Undefined/Fish Head trinket do?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

In the Binding of Isaac expansion Wrath of the Lamb, I got a trinket called Undefined, which looks like the severed head of a green fish. What does this trinket do?

Comment: [I knew I should have asked that before I took a shower...](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70735/what-does-spirit-of-the-night-do).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which Trinkets are available in Wrath of the Lamb?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71059/which-trinkets-are-available-in-wrath-of-the-lamb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the wiki](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Wrath_of_the_Lamb#Trinkets), this is the Fish Head trinket and its effect is to spawn attack flies when Isaac is hit.

Comment: The description on the wiki is inconsistent: it tells it spawns flies when Isaac gets hit, as the Mulligan; the Mulligan description though says that it spawns flies when firing.

Comment: I know, but I assumed their description of the effect was more likely to be accurate than their comparison to another item. If I find out that's not the case, I can change it.

Comment: @Kappei by the way, the description in the wiki is now consistent (and my assumption was correct)